# Custom Parameters in web Dyncamics Crm web resource

Tags: oauth, dynamics-crm, crm, quickbooks, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm creating integration with site that support autorization via OAuth 1. As a OAuth callback I put Crm web resource. But when site executes callback - crm gives me `HTPP 500` because path is something like that `http://crm/webresources/auth.html?oauth_token=<data>&oauth_verifier=<data>&realmId=1381471230&dataSource=QBO`.

Is there any way to enable this get parameters in CRM web resources?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass on custom parameters to CRM.  You have to pass any custom parameters via the standard "data" URL parameter.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327945.aspx

Comment: I ended up adding Js helpers to concatenate them because you also need to escape them using encodeUriComponent... and it was a pain in the ass to do it for every single web resource :)